What is the essence of frequency in DC circuits?
While studying equivalent circuit models for lithium-ion battery packs, I came across the topic of Warburg Impedance. A paragraph from my source (Book Page 40 in preview) goes as follows:

In the literature, it is not uncommon to see equivalent-circuit models containing a so-called Warburg impedance element. For example, the Randles circuit in Fig. 2.8 is a frequently seen equivalent-circuit model of a cell (less the open-circuit voltage) that is inspired by electrochemical principles, somewhat like we will see in later chapters."


It seems like there is this impedance of sorts which come up often when equivalent circuit models are constructed. I fail to follow up when it is stated that this impedance, as the term suggests, is frequency dependent, listed as $$A_W\sqrt{j\omega}$$
I cannot wrap my head around the whole idea of introducing frequencies (\$\omega\$ in the Warburg equation) for circuits which deal with DC currents. The whole application of Li-ion batteries in EVs is in the DC regime. Can someone enlighten me on how I can relate to the frequency in this circuit? Does it have actual significance or is it a way to study the circuit only for convenience? Things grow from introducing Warburg to Nyquist plots and I'm hoping to keep my basics strong.

The battery provides a fixed voltage - in that sense it is DC.
The load (especially in regard to electric vehicles) draws power in spurts - the motors do not run on DC.  In the simplest case, the motor in driven with pulse width modulation.  In any practical electric vehicle, the motor will probably be a brushless DC motor.  The brushless DC motor driver chops the DC into multiphase AC.
The battery has to provide current to match the fluctuating demands of the motor or the motor driver.
I made some measurements of a simple PWM motor control a while back.
The circuit is very simple:

There's an Arduino Nano producing a PWM signal with a variable duty cycle driving a MOSFET that switches power to a small motor:
Varying the pulse width varies the motor speed:

That's the PWM signal.  The motor will draw a high current pulse with each pulse of the driver signal.
If the battery powering the circuit has a high inductance, then the current pulses through the motor would be rounded off.  If the frequency is too high, then the battery won't be able to supply the pulses - the average current flow to the motor would be lower than it should be for a given duty cycle.

As a further example, this question includes some diagrams of the current flow in a brushless DC motor:

The current waveform is anything but DC.  That's why impedance (capacitive and inductive) matters in the battery powering a motor.

The equivalent circuit is correct, since there are no sinusoidal generators, the analysis must be done in the complex frequency domain s, that is, the system is studied with the Laplace transform to determine the voltage, current and power transients.


I cannot wrap my head around the whole idea of introducing frequencies (ω
in the Warburg equation) for circuits which deal with DC currents.

"DC" can mean two completely different things:

Constant voltage or current, has been constant since forever, will be constant forever. Approximated to: variations are small enough to be neglected.

Voltage or current that is not alternating. As in "Directed Current" that means current always goes in the same direction, polarity is always the same, but that doesn't mean it is constant! For example a DC motor will be driven with voltage of constant polarity (unless you want to reverse) but variable amplitude if you want speed control.


In your case your "DC" is the sum of a constant voltage (the battery's nominal voltage) plus a small AC variation on top. It could also be a constant current plus a small AC variation. As long as the AC part is smaller than the DC part, the sum of the two doesn't change sign, which means it can still be called DC.
So if you want to measure the impedance of a battery depending on frequency, to do so you'd use AC current and measure AC voltage... in both cases, added to the DC operating point of the circuit.
Nit-picking: the current in a rechargeable battery is never really DC. At some point you'll have to charge it, to do so you have to reverse direction of the current. So it's really very low frequency AC, with like one period a day or something.

Frequency-dependent measurements are often used to gain insight into the electrochemical processes that occur in batteries. Same thing in other electrochemical processes (electroplating, electrolysis, etc.). Whether this becomes important when modeling the transient response of batteries I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised.

Hi, thanks for this, its a good lead for me at higher level. Would you recommend for me to go through Electrochemical Impedance Spectroscopy of a Lithium Ion cell because this popped up when I was searching along the lines of frequency dependent measurements. If you’re familiar with the term, do you think it will be relative to my question so I should study more about it?

At DC the frequency jw is zero and that model reduces to a simple resistor.

Sure, but if you connect a DC load to battery, the battery first had no load and then it has load and the jump is more complex than explained by pure DC resistance.

Then it's not a DC circuit and you've got a different question then the one asked!

In a real-life circuit and outside of steady state, there are no DC currents. You may have roughly a DC voltage but the currents change a lot and that means they have an AC component that is not negligible.
For your application this is especially true if the battery pack supplies a switching regulator or is charged by one.


The whole application of Li-ion batteries in EVs is in the DC regime.

It isn't, though. Whenever the power demand changes (e.g. because the driver wants the car to accelerate), that's an AC component. An AC analysis tells you how the cell responds to that change.

That makes sense, thanks for your explanation. If it isn’t too much imposing, can you give me some explanation on how this “AC Analysis” is done? I’ll also look it over the web. Is it something similar to what @Franc answered about studying the circuit in Laplace regime?

@OnkarSingh you keep reading the book :)
